# Resampling audio using FFmpeg API

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode, resampling

I have a task to decode audio data, re-encode it to another format, and save this encoded data to a buffer. The encoded data that I need to save to the buffer is in `AVPacket::data`. I save them after this procedure:

1. I receive a packet from the input stream
2. I send the packet to the decoder
3. I get the decrypted frame
4. I send it to the encoder
5. I get the encoded packet
6. Save to the buffer

All procedures work. But here's the problem. I need to create a "resampling" between points 3 and 4. Before sending data to the encoder, it must pass resampling if required. For example, I get audio data in `PCM_ALAW` format, with 1 audio channel, and 8000 sample rate. When exiting, I want to get `PCM_S32LE`, with 2 channels and a sampling rate of 44100. Converting audio format `PCM_ALAW` to `PCM_S32LE` works. But I do not know how to implement resampling.

I have an incomplete implementation of the oversampling functions, but I do not know how to put it all together. I was advised [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/resampling_audio_8c-example.html) and [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcode_aac_8c-example.html) example. But I couldn't solve it.

I provide the full code.

**audiodecoder.h**

```cpp
class AudioDecoder
{
public:

    AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoderSettings& settings);
    AudioDecoder& operator=(const AudioDecoder& other) = delete;
    AudioDecoder& operator=(AudioDecoder&& other)      = delete;
    AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoder& other)            = delete;
    AudioDecoder(AudioDecoder&& other)                 = delete;
    virtual ~AudioDecoder(void);

    virtual qint32 init(void) noexcept;
    //virtual QByteArray getData(const quint32 &size) noexcept;
    virtual QByteArray get() noexcept;
    virtual qint32 term(void) noexcept;

protected:

    virtual qint32 openInputStream (void) noexcept;
    virtual qint32 openEncoderForStream(void) noexcept;
    virtual qint32 decodeAudioFrame(AVFrame *frame);
    virtual qint32 encodeAudioFrame(AVFrame *frame);
    virtual qint32 initResampler(void);
    virtual qint32 initConvertedSamples(uint8_t ***converted_input_samples, int frame_size);

    class Deleter
    {
    public:
        static void cleanup(AVFormatContext* p);
        static void cleanup(AVCodecContext* p);
        static void cleanup(AudioDecoderSettings* p);
    };

protected:

    bool   m_edf;
    bool   m_initialized{ false };
    qint32 m_streamIndex{ 0 };
    QByteArray                                     m_buffer;
    QScopedPointer<AVFormatContext,       Deleter> p_frmCtx{nullptr};
    QScopedPointer<AVCodecContext,        Deleter> p_iCdcCtx{nullptr};
    QScopedPointer<AVCodecContext,        Deleter> p_oCdcCtx{nullptr};
    QScopedPointer<AudioDecoderSettings,  Deleter> p_settings{nullptr};
    SwrContext *swrCtx;
};
```

**audiodecoder.cpp**

```cpp
static void initPacket(AVPacket *packet)
{
    av_init_packet(packet);
    // Set the packet data and size so that
    // it is recognized as being empty.
    packet->data = nullptr;
    packet->size = 0;
}

static QString error2string(const qint32& code)
{
    if (code < 0) {
        char errorBuffer[255]{ '0' };
        av_strerror(code, errorBuffer, sizeof(errorBuffer));
        return QString(errorBuffer);
    }
    return QString();
}

static void printErrorMessage(const QString &message, const qint32 &code = 0)
{
    qDebug() << "AudioDecoder: " << message << error2string(code);
}

static qint32 initInputFrame(AVFrame **frame)
{
    if (!(*frame = av_frame_alloc())) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not allocate input frame"));
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }
    return 0;
}

void AudioDecoder::Deleter::cleanup(AVFormatContext* p)
{
    if (p) {
        avformat_close_input(&p);
    }
}

void AudioDecoder::Deleter::cleanup(AVCodecContext* p)
{
    if (p) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p);
    }
}

void AudioDecoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioDecoderSettings* p)
{
    if (p) {
        delete p;
    }
}

AudioDecoder::AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoderSettings& settings)
    : m_edf(false),
      m_initialized(false)
    , m_streamIndex(0)
    , p_frmCtx(nullptr)
    , p_iCdcCtx(nullptr)
    , p_oCdcCtx(nullptr)
    , p_settings(new AudioDecoderSettings(settings))
{
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::openInputStream(void) noexcept
{
    qint32           error  = -1;
    AVCodecContext  *avctx  = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext *frmCtx = nullptr;

    // Open the input file to read from it.
    if ((error = avformat_open_input(&frmCtx,
            p_settings->inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, nullptr)) < 0) {
        frmCtx = nullptr;
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not open input file '%1' (error '%2')")
                          .arg(p_settings->inputFile()
                          .arg(error2string(error))));
        return error;
    }

    // Get information on the input file (number of streams etc.).
    if ((error = avformat_find_stream_info(frmCtx, nullptr)) < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not open find stream info (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        return error;
    }

    // Find audio stream index
    auto getAudioStreamIndex = [](AVFormatContext *frmCtx) -> qint32
    {
        if (frmCtx->nb_streams != 1) {
            for (quint32 i = 0; i < frmCtx->nb_streams; ++i) {
                if (frmCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    };

    if (frmCtx->streams[m_streamIndex =
            getAudioStreamIndex(frmCtx)]->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        printErrorMessage(QString("The audio stream was not found"));
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodec *codec = nullptr;
    // Find a decoder for the audio stream.
    if (!(codec = avcodec_find_decoder(
              frmCtx->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar->codec_id))) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not find input codec"));
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate a new decoding context.
    avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!avctx) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not allocate a decoding context"));
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    // Initialize the stream parameters with demuxer information.
    error = avcodec_parameters_to_context(
                avctx, frmCtx->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar);
    if (error < 0) {
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        return error;
    }

    // Open the decoder for the audio stream to use it later.
    if ((error = avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, nullptr)) < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not open input codec: "), error);
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        avformat_close_input(&frmCtx);
        return error;
    }

    // Save the decoder context for easier access later.
    p_iCdcCtx.reset(avctx);
    p_frmCtx.reset(frmCtx);

    // Print detailed information about the input format
    av_dump_format(p_frmCtx.data(), 0,
                   p_settings->inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    return 0;
}

AudioDecoder::~AudioDecoder(void)
{
    term();
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::term(void) noexcept
{
    if (!m_initialized) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (p_frmCtx   != nullptr) {
        p_frmCtx.reset();
    }
    if (p_iCdcCtx  != nullptr) {
        p_iCdcCtx.reset();
    }
    if (p_oCdcCtx  != nullptr) {
        p_oCdcCtx.reset();
    }
    if (p_settings != nullptr) {
        p_settings.reset();
    }
    m_initialized = false;
    return (p_frmCtx && p_iCdcCtx && p_oCdcCtx && p_settings) ? -1 : 0;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::init(void) noexcept
{
    if (m_initialized) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (p_settings->inputFile().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (p_settings->audioCodec().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (openInputStream() < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (openEncoderForStream() < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (initResampler() < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    m_initialized = true;
    return 0;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::openEncoderForStream(void) noexcept
{
    AVCodecContext *avctx = nullptr;
    AVCodec        *codec = nullptr;
    qint32          error = 0;

    // Set the basic encoder parameters.
    const quint32 sampleRate   = p_settings->sampleRate()   > 0
            ? p_settings->sampleRate()   : p_iCdcCtx->sample_rate;
    const quint16 channelCount = p_settings->channelCount() > 0
            ? p_settings->channelCount() : p_iCdcCtx->channels;
    const quint32 constBitRate = p_settings->constBitRate() > 0
            ? p_settings->constBitRate() : p_iCdcCtx->bit_rate;
    const QString encodeName   = p_settings->audioCodec() == "copy"
            ? QString(p_iCdcCtx->codec->name) : p_settings->audioCodec();

    if (!(codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(
              encodeName.toStdString().c_str()))) {
        printErrorMessage(QString(
            "Could not find an %1 encoder").arg(p_settings->audioCodec()));
        return -1;
    }

    avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!avctx) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not allocate an encoding context"));
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!codec->sample_fmts) {
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        return -1;
    }

    avctx->channels              = channelCount;
    avctx->channel_layout        = av_get_default_channel_layout(channelCount);
    avctx->sample_rate           = sampleRate;
    avctx->bit_rate              = constBitRate;
    avctx->sample_fmt            = codec->sample_fmts[0];
    // Set the sample rate for the container.
    avctx->time_base.den         = sampleRate;
    avctx->time_base.num         = 1;
    // Allow the use of the experimental encoder.
    avctx->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL;

    // Open the encoder for the audio stream to use it later.
    if ((error = avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, nullptr)) < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not open output codec (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        return -1;
    }

    p_oCdcCtx.reset(avctx);
    return 0;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::decodeAudioFrame(AVFrame *frame)
{
    // Packet used for temporary storage.
    AVPacket input_packet;
    qint32 error = 0;
    initPacket(&input_packet);

    // Read one audio frame from the input file into a temporary packet.
    if ((error = av_read_frame(p_frmCtx.data(), &input_packet)) < 0) {
        // If we are at the end of the file, flush the decoder below.
        if (error == AVERROR_EOF) {
            m_edf = true;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printErrorMessage(QString("Could not read frame (error '%1')")
                              .arg(error2string(error)));
            return error;
        }
    }

    if (input_packet.stream_index != m_streamIndex) {
        av_packet_unref(&input_packet);
        return -1;
    }

    // Send the audio frame stored in the temporary packet to the decoder.
    // The input audio stream decoder is used to do this.
    if ((error = avcodec_send_packet(p_iCdcCtx.data(), &input_packet)) < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not send packet for decoding (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
        return error;
    }

    // Receive one frame from the decoder.
    error = avcodec_receive_frame(p_iCdcCtx.data(), frame);
    // If the decoder asks for more data to be able to decode a frame,
    // return indicating that no data is present.

    if (error == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
        error = 0;
    // If the end of the input file is reached, stop decoding.
    } else if (error == AVERROR_EOF) {
        m_edf = true;
        error = 0;
    } else if (error < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not decode frame (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
    } else {
        error = 0;
    }
    av_packet_unref(&input_packet);
    return error;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::encodeAudioFrame(AVFrame *frame)
{
    /* Packet used for temporary storage. */
    AVPacket output_packet;
    int error;
    initPacket(&output_packet);
    // Send the audio frame stored in the temporary packet to the encoder.
    // The output audio stream encoder is used to do this.
    error = avcodec_send_frame(p_oCdcCtx.data(), frame);
    // The encoder signals that it has nothing more to encode.
    if (error == AVERROR_EOF) {
        error = 0;
    } else if (error < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not send packet for encoding (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
    }
    else {

        // Receive one encoded frame from the encoder.
        error = avcodec_receive_packet(p_oCdcCtx.data(), &output_packet);
        // If the encoder asks for more data to be able to provide an
        // encoded frame, return indicating that no data is present.
        if (error == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
            error = 0;
        /* If the last frame has been encoded, stop encoding. */
        } else if (error == AVERROR_EOF) {
            error = 0;
        } else if (error < 0) {
            printErrorMessage(QString("Could not encode frame (error '%1')")
                              .arg(error2string(error)));
        } else {

            // Copy packet
            // output_packet.pts      = av_rescale_q_rnd(output_packet.pts,  p_iCdcCtx->time_base, p_oCdcCtx->time_base, (enum AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX) );
            // output_packet.dts      = av_rescale_q_rnd(output_packet.dts,  p_iCdcCtx->time_base, p_oCdcCtx->time_base, (enum AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX) );
            // output_packet.duration = av_rescale_q(output_packet.duration, p_iCdcCtx->time_base, p_oCdcCtx->time_base);
            // output_packet.pos      = -1;

            // Save decoded - encoded audio data
            for (int i = 0; i < output_packet.size; ++i) {
                m_buffer.push_back(output_packet.data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    av_packet_unref(&output_packet);
    return error;
}

QByteArray AudioDecoder::get() noexcept
{
    AVFrame *frame = nullptr;
    if (initInputFrame(&frame) < 0) {
        return m_buffer;
    }

    while (!m_edf) {
        if (decodeAudioFrame(frame) < 0) {
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            return m_buffer;
        }

        // ????
        uint8_t **converted_input_samples = nullptr;
        if (initConvertedSamples(&converted_input_samples, frame->nb_samples) < 0) {
            if (converted_input_samples) {
                av_freep(&converted_input_samples[0]);
                free(converted_input_samples);
            }
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            return {};
        }



        if (encodeAudioFrame(frame) < 0) {
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            return m_buffer;
        }
        av_frame_unref(frame);
    }
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return m_buffer;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::initResampler(void)
{
    qint32 error = 0;
    // Create a resampler context for the conversion.
    // Set the conversion parameters. Default channel layouts based on the number of channels
    // are assumed for simplicity (they are sometimes not detected properly by the demuxer and/or decoder).
    swrCtx = swr_alloc_set_opts(
                nullptr,
                av_get_default_channel_layout(p_oCdcCtx->channels), p_oCdcCtx->sample_fmt, p_oCdcCtx->sample_rate,
                av_get_default_channel_layout(p_iCdcCtx->channels), p_iCdcCtx->sample_fmt, p_iCdcCtx->sample_rate,  0,
                nullptr);
    if (!swrCtx) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not allocate resample context"));
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    // Perform a sanity check so that the number of converted samples is
    // not greater than the number of samples to be converted.
    // If the sample rates differ, this case has to be handled differently
    av_assert0(p_oCdcCtx->sample_rate == p_iCdcCtx->sample_rate);

    // Open the resampler with the specified parameters.
    if ((error = swr_init(swrCtx)) < 0) {
        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not open resample context"));
        swr_free(&swrCtx);
        return error;
    }
    return 0;
}

qint32 AudioDecoder::initConvertedSamples(uint8_t ***converted_input_samples, int frame_size)
{
    qint32 error = 0;
    // Allocate as many pointers as there are audio channels.
    // Each pointer will later point to the audio samples of the corresponding
    // channels (although it may be NULL for interleaved formats).
    if (!(*converted_input_samples =
            (uint8_t **) calloc(p_oCdcCtx->channels, sizeof(**converted_input_samples)))) {
        printErrorMessage("Could not allocate converted input sample pointers");
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }
    
    // Allocate memory for the samples of all channels in one consecutive
    // block for convenience
    if ((error = av_samples_alloc(
             *converted_input_samples,
             nullptr,
             p_oCdcCtx->channels,
             frame_size,
             p_oCdcCtx->sample_fmt,
             0)) < 0) {

        printErrorMessage(QString("Could not allocate converted input samples (error '%1')")
                          .arg(error2string(error)));
        av_freep(&(*converted_input_samples)[0]);
        free(*converted_input_samples);
        return error;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is where I have to implement data resampling before sending it to the encoder:

```cpp
QByteArray AudioDecoder::get() noexcept
{
    AVFrame *frame = nullptr;
    if (initInputFrame(&frame) < 0) {
        return m_buffer;
    }

    while (!m_edf) {
        if (decodeAudioFrame(frame) < 0) {
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            return m_buffer;
        }

        // ???
        // ???
        // ???
        // This is where I have to implement data 
        // resampling before sending it to the encoder
        // ???
        // ???
        // ???

        if (encodeAudioFrame(frame) < 0) {
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            return m_buffer;
        }
        av_frame_unref(frame);
    }
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return m_buffer;
}
```

Comment: While you can insert extra values, you cannot add information. Your input signal is limited (per the Nyquist Theorem) to 4 khz (8000/2), and your output signal will be limited to the same 4 kHz.

Comment: @MSalters, I agree, but then why does the ffmpeg utility allow conversions from 8kHz to 48kHz for example.

Comment: There might be a technical necessity. CD's for instance are always 44100 Hz (it's where that strange number comes from).

Comment: Also, `initResampler` contains `av_assert0(p_oCdcCtx->sample_rate == p_iCdcCtx->sample_rate);` and an explicit comment saying that there shall be no resampling. That seems to be in direct contradiction with the stated intent.

Comment: Then it turns out that it makes no sense for me to change the sample rate(since it is impossible), only if it is required, the number of channels, bitrate and sample format ?

Comment: I suspect that you have something a bit more complex than just a simple coding problem. There could be a bigger problem, and you may need someone with actual audio knowledge and an understanding of the larger program architecture.

Comment: @MSalters, In my case, I just have to open the audio file and extract the audio data without decoding. If the client needs to change the format, for example from `PCM_ALAW` to `PCM_MULAW`, then i will have to send the decoded data to the encoder, and then save the decoded data to the buffer. It would also be cool to change the number of output channels, the sample format, and so on at the client's request.

Comment: @MSalters, Why I turned my attention to changing the sample rate is because the ffmpeg utility allows you to do this. The following command accepts an input audio file with 1 channel, a sample rate of 8000, and audio formats - PCM_ALAW. At the output, we get an audio file with the PCM_S32LE audio format, with a sampling rate of 44100, and with 2 audio channels: `ffmpeg -f alaw -ac 1 -ar 8000 -i input.mka -f s32le -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 2 -ar 44100 output.mka`